# Application scope PropertyPlaceHolder Spring in Mule

Tags: spring, mule, placeholder

I'am using Mule CE 3.3.0 and I have a problem with the PropertyPlaceHolder's scope. Let's suppose that I have two mule application (writeApp and readApp). In the writeApp application I set a propertyPlaceholer bean as defined below:

```
<spring:bean id="consignmentProperty" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <spring:property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <spring:property name="locations">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>classpath:connections.properties</spring:value>
                    <spring:value>.....</spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
</spring:bean>
```

And in the readApp application I try to read the property defined in the writeApp

```
<mule>
    <flow name="readContextVariableFlow1" doc:name="readContextVariableFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8085" path="read" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <append-string-transformer message="${prop.conn}" doc:name="Append String"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The problem is that right now I'am able to read the prop.conn property from readApp, although it is defined in the writeApp. I would able to define a specific file property for each application.

Thank you in advance for any kind of help

Comment: When you say "app" you really mean Mule Application (ie. a zip file deployed on Mule standalone), not a flow, right?

Comment: yes, I mean mule application, i.e. the zip file

Comment: Thanks for the precision. Then, wow, this is surprising, unless Spring loads these props in system properties in one app and picks them up from system props in the other app.

Comment: Any reason why you use the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class directly instead of the `<context:property-placeholder />` element.

Answer (score 0):

You could namespace your properties to prevent cross-sharing, like "readApp.prop.conn" and "writeApp.prop.conn".

Alternatively, try turning system properties off:

```
<spring:beans>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:connections.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" system-properties-mode="NEVER" />
</spring:beans>
```

Comment: Yes, I know but i would something that avoid the visibility of one file rather than another one in two different mule applications

Comment: Ok, do you know if it is possible to have one config file just for one application and that it not be shared among applications?

Comment: I thought that was the case, I don't understand how the properties loaded in one app can be available to another app unless they are also loaded and resolved as system properties. Did you try my second proposal?

Comment: do you mean to use the <app-name>.* notation? Yes, it's work, but my prerogative should be to have one file visible just for one app and your solution, although it is a smart solution, it does not fix the issue that I have

Comment: When I paste your code, I got this error: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'spring-context:property-placeholder' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.

Comment: I tried to use the spring property _systemPropertiesMode_ with value = 0 (NEVER), but it does not work, i.e the behaviour is the same: if I define a property file in writeApp and I try to read any of its property in the readApp, I am able to read it. I shouldn't..

Comment: You need to declare the `spring-context` namespace using its standard declaration from Spring. At this point, I would say it is a bug: applications shouldn't see properties loaded in other application, if they are not stored in system property. I suggest you JIRA it at http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE